# Влияет ли общее количество очков, заработанных на разных площадках StackExchange, на что-либо?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, репутация

Есть ли какие-либо дополнительные возможности выдаваемые пользователям, которые "насобирали" определённое количество очков на разных площадках StackExchange?

Comment: Влияет на циферки во flair: https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2016377.png

Answer (score 13):

Знаю только про [бонус за ассоциацию](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/08/cross-site-account-associations/). Если на каком-либо сайте сети у вас 200+ репутации, то при создании аккаунта на другом сайте вам дадут 100 репутации.

А это, в свою очередь, сразу открывает некоторые [базовые возможности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: Да, точно, хороший пример. Но 200 набрать можно относительно быстро. А вот, что насчёт тех, у кого несколько тысяч, десятков.

Comment: @edem я больше ничего не встречал)

Comment: Не просто на другом сайте, а на обоих сайтах :)

Comment: @PashaPash вы не правы. `+100` только на новом сообществе.

Comment: @doox911 при первой ассоциации новыми считаются оба сообщества :)

Comment: @PashaPash а здесь вы правы)

Comment: @doox911, на каждом сайте по +100, но только по 1 разу и если сайтов хотя бы 2.

Answer (score 5):

> А вот, что насчёт тех, у кого несколько тысяч, десятков.

Большая и толстая репа однозначно влияет. Но это скорее из области психологии.

Не претендую на однозначность своих наблюдений и выводов, это сугубо моё личное мнение.

Не хотелось бы, как-то разделять психологию западных и отечественных пользователей, но она  немного всё таки отличается.

На западных ресурсах в большинстве своём законопослушные люди, которые соблюдают в основном правила, инструкции.
  Велика вера и поклонение к успеху, то есть к высореповым пользователям.
 Это видно по топикам, где есть  несколько ответов от людей с разной репой. Галочка мгновенно отдается высокореповому участнику. Его ответ самый лучший? Да не всегда, но у него самая толстая репа, значит от знает и делает, по твердому убеждению западного пользователя, намного лучше.
Ответ от низкорепового участника не торопятся принимать, могут на день, два сделать паузу. Потому-что доверия меньше.

Иногда доходит до смешных случаев. Высокореповый участник говорит, что сделать это невозможно, потому что это баг браузера. Если появляется ответ решающий проблему без костылей, то надо ещё потрудиться, добавить примеров, чтобы его признали.
Ниже мой нескромный [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57964904/7394871)

По моим наблюдениям, чем больше становится репа, тем больше становится доверия в виде галочек, плюсов.
Ты становишься более интересен для рядового пользователя, больше просматривается твой профиль, больше переходов по ссылкам из профиля.
 *Других плюсов от количества репы на разных сайтах, я тоже не заметил, кроме конечно более широкого погружения в свою специализацию.*

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, ты не на тот вопрос отвечаешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy я же сразу предупредил, что мой ответ, чисто моё, сугубо личное мнение и затрагивает чисто психологические нюансы, а не машинизированную систему бонусов.

Answer (score 4):

1. На каждой площадке привилегии выдаются в соответствии с рейтингом, заработанным на ней. На мете используется репутация с основного сайта, хотя в скрытом формате считается и собственная, за которую дают знаки.
2. Есть приветственный бонус в 100 баллов на каждом сайте за то, что хотя бы на одном из нескольких ты набрал достаточно репутации - это позволяет сразу получить базовые привилегии типа комментирования.
3. Чат использует суммарную репутацию по всем сайтам (или всем сайтам, с которыми он сгруппирован), но там нужно всего 20 баллов, чтобы можно было свободно писать, больше ни на что репутация там не влияет.
4. Судя по всему, привилегии в командах выдаются в соответствии с репутацией на основном сайте, но я не уверен. Собственная репутация там есть и отображается явно.

Comment: На сейчас два примера: доступ к беседке и +100 очков на других площадках.